# Force/request/educate beginners to "@notify"

Tags: feature-request, comments, new-users, comment-replies

Too often I see comments (from multiple people) asking for clarifications about questions and then a while later the question author does respond but doesn't address/notify anybody with the "@user" functionality. So the people asking for the clarifications never see the responses. Or even if they do stick around or revisit the question without being notified, it's not always clear who each response is for. But my main issue is the missing notifications.

I find this quite annoying and wasteful. It's most often beginners who fail to address/notify people, probably because they don't even know that that notification feature exists. Could the system force, request or at least very noticeably educate people to appropriately address/notify via @user whenever they write a comment under their question and there's more than one other commenter? (In case of only one other commenter, that one already does get notified anyway.)

To make an explicit suggestion: When they try to submit a comment under their question with comments from multiple others and it doesn't have any correct "@user", show them an explanation/warning and choice somewhat like this:

> Your comment isn't addressed to anyone. Nobody will get notified about your response, so whoever you're responding to might never see your response. Also, it might be unclear who you're responding to. You can write "@username" to address the appropriate user, and then that user will be notified.
>
> [Ok, I'll do that. Let me edit my comment.](http://this-goes-back-to-editing-the-comment.com/)
>
> [No, thanks, this isn't responding to anyone. Please post my comment as is.](http://this-posts-the-comment.com/) (Be aware that this usually means you're adding information to your question, which you'd better edit right into your question instead.)

(Since the system (as far as I know) doesn't allow addressing/notifying several people, the above text could also suggest to split the comment into several if it actually contains several comments that would better be addressed to several people. Then again, I'd rather keep it short.)

A lightweight alternative suggestion: Instead of the above block, just ask `Who are you talking to?` and show them the people and have them pick one. And then insert the @user for them.
(Note: I just added this alternative. I don't think it really changes my question as the point is to make them address/notify at all, not so much *how* to achieve that. But for clarity let me say the current votes are 83 up, 10 down).

Comment: I like the idea of having some sort of "reply to" function that will auto @notify.  I think it should be an icon next to the upvote/flag comment icons. Another issue is that we can only notify one person at a time, when sometimes I want to post 1 reply, to 2 people, or keep the comments down by combining replies into a comment.  Also, if someone comments on an answer, the Answer OP WILL see the comment, and the question OP MIGHT as well, but I'm not 100% sure on the latter.

Comment: Side note: "Nobody will get notified" is not true while there are only 1 commenter in addition to OP.

Comment: This will just encourage these users to add @notifications to make the "error message" go away, spamming other hapless users who don't actually care about their "plz can u answer muh question?" comment. This might be elitist, but I rather liked it when the ability to notify another user in a comment was a "hidden" feature. It kept down inbox spam.

Comment: As @AlexeiLevenkov correctly mentions your claim is false. The user asking for clarification **will** get a notification independently from the usage of `@user` from the OP if he's the only one to comment on the question.  If multiple people comment then the chances are that someone will read the response anyway and so I don't really see the issue with the current system.

Comment: @Bakuriu No one came back to read this guy's replies, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39800121/ at least not very quickly. I'm not saying it's an important issue, but I don't find your "I think it unlikely" argument convincing, since, yes, it does actually happen.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yes, I know. I'm only talking about the cases I describe in the first paragraph, i.e., where the problem does happen. Sorry for being sloppy, I'll rewrite it to make that clear.

Comment: @CodyGray I doubt they would address the wrong person much. And I don't see how addressing the right person could be bad. If you say that because I had asked to make them "address/notify *someone*": I didn't mean "*someone*" as in "randomly pick one to spam" but as in "pick one appropriately". Because often a reply answers several people's question, and because the system as far as I know sadly doesn't allow to address/notify them all. I reworded that now.

Comment: @Bakuriu Like I just said to Alexei, I wasn't talking about those cases and made that clearer now. And I disagree with your latter part. Often the OP replies only like 30 minutes later, when the question is already pretty much dead and so pretty much *nobody* sees the responses. Also, other people seeing the response isn't nearly as good as the asker seeing the response. I'm often in that position - I don't want to wait or remember to come back, but I don't want to miss a reply, either.

Comment: @Bakuriu And I often see that others asked something and that the OP responded without telling them and that it has been a long time since, so the askers probably never saw it. I find that quite painful to see, especially if I can tell that the asker could've really used the response to continue well.

Comment: @XaolingBao That "reply" icon would better not be invisible until hovered-over like the upvote/flag icons are now, though. And even then, people might ignore it and comment as usual. Hmm... maybe that "reply" icon should become the *only* way for the OP to comment :-). Not joking, actually. About the issue of addressing combined comments to several people: I think most of the time they should just not be combined in the first place. I added a bit at the end of my question about this now.

Comment: Combining posts is to save from you posting 5x comments in a row, like you just did here.  The reply could be invisible, just like upvote/flag, because people know where they are, and see them appear.

Comment: @XaolingBao Even if my five comments weren't too long to fit into one (because of the 600 characters limit), I wouldn't have wanted to combine them (except for the two to Bakariu). There's nothing wrong with posting several comments in a row. I usually find it cleaner, and it allows separate deletion. If for some reason I want to delete one, I can. If I combined them instead, I could only delete all or none. And about "people know where they are": No. Remember we're specifically talking here about people **not** knowing how things work.

Comment: I'd hate to see '_No, thanks, this isn't responding to anyone. Please post my comment as is._' because of the '_this isn't responding to anyone._' part. Maybe I am replying to someone but just don't want to use the notify system. Or take this comment for instance, I'm replying to anyone who'll read it, literally ANYONE. Don't make me lie to post my reply.

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland I can't quite take your comment for instance, as this is my question, not yours. That's not the described situation. But I do see the problem. How about *"No, thanks, I don't want to notify anyone. Please post my comment as is."*? (Not sure I should change the text in the suggestion, since there are so many votes now and I don't want to misrepresent them...)

Comment: @StefanPochmann - How about just, '_No thanks, please post my comment as is._' and stop trying to attribute reason to the user's actions? But you are right, the minutiae of the message isn't the crux of the issue here, sorry for bringing it up.

Comment: @codygray Tell me more about this "inbox spam" problem.  I am interested!  Anyone else also interested?

Comment: @StefanPochmann - Just noticed this part of the question '_the point is to make them address/notify at all, not so much how to achieve that._' If the point isn't how to achieve it then sorry but I can't see what you are looking for in answers, could you clarify? I've put an answer on how to improve visibility but upon reflect that is clearly a _how_ answer, I can't think how else to answer though?

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland I'm not really looking for "answers". This is a [**feature request**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/feature-request/info). I believe this is the way to communicate a suggestion like this to the company and get feedback about it from the community (votes, comments, perhaps answers). I'd say your answer is alright, makes sense as answer. And note I said it's not "so much" about the "how". I mainly said it to explain why I think the edit isn't misrepresenting previous votes. But this is *also* about the "how".

Comment: @StefanPochmann missed the tag as well. Man I suck at SO'ing, but the only way to get better is practice, right?!

Comment: @CodyGray I don't think I've ever seen a "plz can u answer muh question?"  comment. Does that actually happen? What I do see *every day* is commenters asking a question and clearly wanting an answer, and then they do get an answer, but aren't told about it.

Comment: *"Does that actually happen?"* Yes, frequently. In fact, my experience is precisely opposite yours. I hardly ever see someone who has received a quality response but is not aware of it, because the people delivering those quality responses read the help and know how to use the site. On the other hand, help vampires haven't read the help, don't know how to use the site, and if presented with an "error message" as you suggest, would just click to notify anyone who was around that they needed some help. I do not want any part of that. I get hundreds of notifications per week that are just noise.

Comment: @Bakuriu I am personally annoyed by the fact that I need to manually go back and check questions I've commented on to see if they've received responses. And yes, this does happen to me.

Comment: Coming from the other side of this issue: it would be nice to have a "subscribe to notifications from this comment thread" post. I'm sure such a feature request would be denied because it's too "social network-y", but jeez, it's a *really useful feature* of social networks, and it would be quite useful as long as you're not *automatically* subscribed whenever you comment.

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps something like this would add enough additional visibility without ramming it down people's retina?

[image]

Replace 'commenters' with a concise description of whatever the rules allow you to tag: '...to  tag another commenter', '...to tag the author or another commenter.', I don't know the rules so will leave the exact details to the gurus.

For those who haven't commented before, this box and text, minus the last sentence, appears when you click 'add a comment'.

Comment: We cannot rely on people reading that pale text.  They see a text box and click.  Words then appear.  The point of the suggestion is that there are very few valid reasons for someone to comment on their own post that are not a @ reply; usually the original post should be edited.

Comment: Apologies to all the users (like me) who are now having trouble navigating the page because the unexpected comment box and UI is throwing off their navigation!

Comment: Nice - but who reads the small *grey* print? Anyway, *commenters* - plural - suggests more than the system is capable of.

Comment: I'd say lots of people. It's two line and is filling up the box you want to type in, it's pretty hard to see it and _not_ read it as a result.

Comment: I didn't know about the existing grey text until now :-). Well, I probably did read and know it when I started here. But I also doubt new people read, understand and follow it. On another site I visit a lot, where most people post little programs, such grey text shows them how to format code. And every single day tons of newbs just ignore it and post unreadable unformatted code and don't care.

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland The question author actually sees not what you said but a different text: *"Use comments to reply to other users or notify them of changes. If you are adding new information, edit your post instead of commenting."*

Comment: As a new user, I'd probably be confused as to why I would want to "tag" another commenter. ("Tags" are generally for categorizing questions, after all.) Better to word it so the fact the other user receives a notification is explicitly stated.

Comment: @jmbpiano - really? I would have thought from the context it is pretty clear they are different concepts. It's something that could be factored in if it is anticipated to be a wide spread issue though.

Comment: I honestly don't think any significant number of people are going to read that text. If we just want to present the user with some information on how to notify users, I recommend showing the formatting help box by default for new users instead. http://i.imgur.com/r2DSUzI.png

Comment: @Ajedi32 - Very cool, if that could be added in subtlety, maybe reorganise it a bit so the notifying info is more prominent as it seems more important, then that could work.

Comment: Although it does irk me when people say 'I don't think people will read that textbox' and then as a solution suggest displaying _another_ textbox. So they won't read the first one but they'll the second?

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland The light grey help text is a lot less obvious and disappears as soon as the user starts typing.

Answer (score -25):

[Stack Overflow is not a forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/is-stack-overflow-a-forum). Why would you want to encourage a forum-like discussion in comments?

Encourage the OP to edit their question instead. It will bump the question up and thus notify everyone interested.

**Exactly** the same thing with answers. Edit your answer in response of comments instead of entangling yourself into long educational session in comments.

Comment: (1) People are going to keep writing comments anyway. I'm just trying to make that actually work instead of being a constant complete painful waste. (2) By far not every response would better be a question edit. For example when the OP asks what the commenter means or something else just isn't clear yet. (3) I **never** get notified about question edits, and I'm sure there must have been many where I had commented. What am I missing? (4) I'd like your way as well, if that worked. My *"Be aware ... you'd better edit right into your question instead"* already goes in that direction.

Comment: I agree we should encourage question authors to improve their questions, through editing of the question itself. But that does not address the issue of commenting, which is the topic of the suggestion above. Fact is, it can take some back-and-forth in the comments to get to a point where the OP understands what they need to add to their post. If no one is eligible for notification of their comments, it seems useful to provide a help box to nudge them in the right direction. That box can include a suggestion to edit the question if appropriate, but it should also address the concern raised here

Comment: Also, I think you're taking *"Is Stack Overflow a forum?"* too far and are misrepresenting the answers there. I just checked the top three. They all point out the **questions** and **answers** as the thing differing from a forum and not being discussions. And the top two answers don't talk about comments and the third explicitly says *"We have a forum aspect in terms of limited discussion in comments"*. Edit: I looked at the remaining two answer now, they also agree with this.